# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 38.3 Gb while creating a document term matrix

Tags: r, vector, size, term-document-matrix

It's the first time that I post on Stackoverflow, I'm a student. I hope someone will be able to help me. I am trying to do sentiment analysis in R Studio and am facing vector size error:

When I try to create a Document Term Matrix using this code:

```
dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)
```

I get the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 38.3 Gb".

The dtm is the DocumentTermMatrix of a corpus that has 178884 elements, 26.7 Mb and the text consist of reviews.

I read all the other response on StackOverflow but I do not understand them and probably they don't apply to my issue. How can I increase the size of a vector in R Studio? I am using RStudio Version 1.2.5001 on a Windows 64 machine.

Is there any other information to provide?

Comment: Basically the amount of information is beyond your computer's ability to handle.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I guess I will have to cut down my dataset. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A document-term matrix (the generic object, not the class in the `tm` package) is typically a count of the number of times a word (in a column) occur in a document (in a row). The columns are the vocabulary for the entire corpus.  In the OPs case, there are 178,884 unique words in the vocabulary. What this means is that for each row there are lots of zeros -- the matrix is very sparse.

In most text analysis packages, the DTM is represented using a special kind of matrix that does not allocate memory for those zeros. For example, in the `tm` package the DTM is actually a  `simple_triplet_matrix` from the `slam` package and in `quanteda` it is a `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package.

Now, if we take either special class of matrix and convert it to a base `R` matrix using `as.matrix()`, `R` is now having to allocate memory for every cell in the matrix including those zeros. This why a DTM that is only a few dozen Mbs as a  `simple_triplet_matrix` or a  `sparseMatrix` will be a few dozen Gbs as a base `R` "dense" matrix.

The solution, then is to use tools from the `slam` or the `Matrix` package on the DTM instead of using `as.matrix()`. These packages have all the typical matrix operation functions, but specific to sparse matrix classes. For example, to use `rowsum` in base `R` would be `row_sums()` in the `slam` package or `rowSums()` in the `Matrix` package.